# C: free freeing more than I want

Tags: c, data-structures, valgrind, free

I've asked a few questions about this before, but I think I've found the root cause of the problem.

I have a program mainLex.c which contains this loop:

```
for (;;)  {
    printf ("(%d)$ ", ncmd);                // Prompt for command
    if ((line = getLine(stdin)) == NULL)    // Read line
        break;                              // Break on end of file

    cmd = hExpand (line, &status);          // Expand line
    free (line);
    if (status > 0)                         // Substitution?
        fputs (cmd, stdout);                //   Print expanded line
    else if (status < 0)
        fputs ("substitution failed\n", stderr);

    list = lex (cmd);                       // Lex line into tokens
    free (cmd);
    if (list == NULL)                       // Empty token list?
        continue;

    hRemember (ncmd, list);                 // Remember command
    if (status >= 0)                        // No substitution error?
        process (list);                     //   Process token list

    freeList (list);                        // Free token list
    ncmd++;                                 // Adjust prompt
    }
```

After running through the loop once, the method is supposed to free the list at freeList, then ask for a new string to use as list. This is all well and good, but I'm finding that freeList is freeing things that I'm not asking it to! In particular, it is freeing a global static data structure llist, and I'm not sure how this is happening.

The code for freeList:

```
void freeList (token *list)
{
    token *p, *pnext;
    for (p = list;  p;  p = pnext)  {
        pnext = p->next;
        free(p->text);
        free(p); //This is apparently where the data structure is being freed
    }
}
```

hRemember:

```
void hRemember (int ncmd, token *list)
{
    command* curr;
    curr = (struct command *)malloc(sizeof(struct command));
    token *list1 = malloc(sizeof(token));
    list1=list;
    f = ncmd;
    curr->cmmd=(struct token *)malloc(sizeof(struct token));
    curr->cmmd=list1;
    curr->num=ncmd;
    curr->prev=llist;
    if (llist==NULL)
    {
        llist = (struct command *)malloc(sizeof(struct command));
    }
    llist->nextcmd=curr;
    llist=curr;
}
```

llist:

```
typedef struct command {          // Struct for each token in linked list
    token *cmmd;                   //   String containing token
    int num;                     //   Corresponding type
    struct command *prev;
    struct command *nextcmd;      //   Pointer to next token in linked list
} command;


command* llist = NULL; //This is global in a different c file than the loop
```

After I try to read llist's contents after one version of the loop, this is what comes up:

```
==12878== Invalid read of size 8
==12878==    at 0x400DB5: hDump (Lex1.c:153)
==12878==    by 0x400BA9: process (mainLex.c:66)
==12878==    by 0x400B0C: main (mainLex.c:41)
==12878==  Address 0x51f34f0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 24 free'd
==12878==    at 0x4C29577: free (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==12878==    by 0x400C0E: freeList (mainLex.c:81)
==12878==    by 0x400B18: main (mainLex.c:43)
==12878== 
==12878== Invalid read of size 1
```

If possible, I would like to not change either the loop or freeList.

EDIT: lex routine, which uses llist (I need to clean this up a lot, but it's functional as of now)

```
token *lex (const char *line)
{
    if (strcspn(line, METACHARS)==strlen(line))
    {
        token *head, *temp, *right, *temp1;
        char *line1 = strdup(line);
        char *curr = separate(line1);
        temp = (token *)malloc(sizeof(token));
        temp->text=strdup(curr);
        temp->type=10;
        head=temp;
        head->next=NULL;
        curr=separate(NULL);
        while (curr!=NULL)
        {
            temp1 = (token *)malloc(sizeof(token));
            right = head;
            while (right->next != NULL)
            {
                right=right->next;

            }
            temp1->text=strdup(curr);
            temp1->type=10;
            temp1->next=NULL;
            right->next=temp1;
            curr=separate(NULL);
        }
        return head;
    }
    else
    {
        token *head, *temp, *right, *temp1;
        char *line1 = strdup(line);
        char *curr = separate(line1);
        temp = (token *)malloc(sizeof(token));
        temp->text=strdup(curr);
        if (strcmp(temp->text,"<")==0)
        {
            temp->type=20;
        }
        else if (strcmp(temp->text,"<<")==0)
        {
            temp->type=21;
        }
        else if (strcmp(temp->text,"|")==0)
        {
            temp->type=30;
        }
        else if (strcmp(temp->text,">")==0)
        {
            temp->type=31;
        }
        else if (strcmp(temp->text,">>")==0)
        {
            temp->type=32;
        }
        else if (strcmp(temp->text,";")==0)
        {
            temp->type=40;
        }
        else if (strcmp(temp->text,"&")==0)
        {
            temp->type=41;
        }
        else if (strcmp(temp->text,"&&")==0)
        {
            temp->type=42;
        }
        else if (strcmp(temp->text,"||")==0)
        {
            temp->type=43;
        }
        else if (strcmp(temp->text,"(")==0)
        {
            temp->type=50;
        }
        else if (strcmp(temp->text,")")==0)
        {
            temp->type=51;
        }
        else
        {
            temp->type=10;
        }

        head=temp;
        head->next=NULL;
        curr=separate(NULL);
        while (curr!=NULL)
        {
            temp1 = (token *)malloc(sizeof(token));
            right = head;
            while (right->next != NULL)
            {
                right=right->next;

            }
            temp1->text=strdup(curr);
            if (strcmp(temp1->text,"<")==0)
            {
                temp1->type=20;
            }
            else if (strcmp(temp1->text,"<<")==0)
            {
                temp1->type=21;
            }
            else if (strcmp(temp1->text,"|")==0)
            {
                temp1->type=30;
            }
            else if (strcmp(temp1->text,">")==0)
            {
                temp1->type=31;
            }
            else if (strcmp(temp1->text,">>")==0)
            {
                temp1->type=32;
            }
            else if (strcmp(temp1->text,";")==0)
            {
                temp1->type=40;
            }
            else if (strcmp(temp1->text,"&")==0)
            {
                temp1->type=41;
            }
            else if (strcmp(temp1->text,"&&")==0)
            {
                temp1->type=42;
            }
            else if (strcmp(temp1->text,"||")==0)
            {
                temp1->type=43;
            }
            else if (strcmp(temp1->text,"(")==0)
            {
                temp1->type=50;
            }
            else if (strcmp(temp1->text,")")==0)
            {
                temp1->type=51;
            }
            else
            {
                temp1->type=10;
            }
            temp1->next=NULL;
            right->next=temp1;
            curr=separate(NULL);
        }
        return head;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd consider renaming your `list` object, even if it is just to `my_list`. The parser in my head keeps confusing it with `std::list`.  Maybe `token_list` would be a good name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In hRemember you have:

```
curr->cmmd=(struct token *)malloc(sizeof(struct token));
curr->cmmd=list1;
```

You allocate the memory, and then leak it by assigning a different pointer to ->cmmd right after allocating.  You should be copying the memory.  Since you aren't, ->cmmd is assigned to the same address as what you `free()` in the main loop, then after the loop you are trying to print it out and this pointer no longer points to valid memory.

You should have:

```
curr->cmmd=(struct token *)malloc(sizeof(struct token));
memcpy(curr->cmmd, list1, sizeof(struct token));
```

Same problem, different place, the line:

```
llist->nextcmd=curr;
```

Should be:

```
memcpy(llist->nextcmd, curr, sizeof(struct command));
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense. It seems it hasn't fixed all my issues, but I have a sneaking suspicion that these other issues are related to the same thing.